# Spring @EnableRetry throws InternalAutoProxyCreator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-retry

I created sample `Spring-boot` application and it works fine without any error,

now I want to practice `spring-retry` to retry some of the methods. If i don't use `@EnableRetry` my application starts without any errors but retry is not working.

If I use `@EnableRetry` on config class my application failed to start

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
  jcenter()
  }

 dependencies {

        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web
         compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.0.RELEASE'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka
         compile group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka', version: '2.2.0.RELEASE'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging
         compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
         // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry
         compile group: 'org.springframework.retry', name: 'spring-retry', version: '1.2.0.RELEASE'

}
```

**Config**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry;

@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class RetryConfig {

 }
```

**retry service**

```
@Service
public class RetryService {

 @Retryable(value = { CustomException.class },  maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay=1000))
 public Optional<String> requestOne(int value){
    if(value ==1) {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
    return Optional.of(" request one method");
}

@Retryable(value = { CustomException.class },  maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay=1000))
public Optional<Integer> requestTwo(int value){
    if(value ==1) {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
    return Optional.of(1);
}

@Recover
public Optional<String> recovery(CustomException ex, int value){
    return Optional.of(" recovery method ");
  }

}
```

**ERROR**

```
2018-12-09 22:56:18.951  WARN 32113 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Pointcut
2018-12-09 22:56:18.961  INFO 32113 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
 2018-12-09 22:56:18.968 ERROR 32113 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Pointcut
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at com.mtpc.MtpcMain.main(MtpcMain.java:10) [bin/:na]
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Pointcut
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.<clinit>(AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:62) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.initBeanFactory(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:82) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.setBeanFactory(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:63) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1732) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
... 15 common frames omitted

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
... 21 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Retry expect [aspect dependencies](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/30) which be solved using 2 solutions:

> including `spring-boot-starter-aop` solved this for me and ensured versioning compatibility with the rest of Spring Boot.

Or

> add the following dependency into my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
</dependency>
```